# PyTorch installation fails Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

I'm trying to install [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) with PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.3 x64 and Python 3.9.0 on Windows 10 pro 64-bit OS PC machine

I've tried:

```
pip install torch==1.7.0+cpu torchvision==0.8.1+cpu torchaudio===0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

and:

```
python -m pip install torch==1.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Should I downgrade Python version, let's say to Python 3.8.6 or PyTorch version, to make it work, or am I doing something else incorrectly  besides this, maybe missed something to install, for example I did not selected CUDA, but seems like it is different reason:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> torch==1.7.0+cpu (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.7.0+cpu

with `pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu//torch-1.7.0%2Bcpu-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl`:

> ERROR: torch-1.7.0+cpu-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported
> wheel on this platform.

and

```
pip install torch==1.4.0+cpu torchvision==0.5.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html -vvv
```

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> torch==1.4.0+cpu (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.4.0+cpu

Any advice, guide or example would be helpful

**Solution:**

Installed successfully with Python 3.8.6

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/34798) post should help you a little bit.

Comment: The simple answer to your question seems that PyTorch 1.7 does not support python 3.9, see [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/34798#issuecomment-728856140).

Comment: @MacOS Hello,  I've tried 1.4.0 as shown at the in my post, but it is same error. Then which version will be suitable?

Comment: @If80 I would recommend trying out python 3.8. If this does not work, try python 3.7. Please report back if any of it worked.

Comment: After a little bit of research, I found this ```It is recommended that you use Python 3.6, 3.7 or 3.8, which can be installed via any of the mechanisms above .``` [here](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/).

Comment: @MacOS I've edited post with solution. Installed with Python 3.8.6. Thank you for feedback and  answer

Comment: Great! You are welcome. :)

Answer (score 4):

I tried with Python 3.8.0, Python 3.8.5, Python 3.8.6 and Python 3.9.0. It seems to work only with 3.8.6 version.